# How to test that pressing <enter> on an HTML input element causes the form to submit

Tags: javascript

Suppose you have:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="tbInput" text="foo" />
</form>
```

It turns out somebody wrote the following code:

```
$("#tbInput").on("keypress", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        // bad code!
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

This is *not* the desired behavior, as pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> to submit a form is often what the user wants to happen.

How can I test that pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> on `#tbInput` causes the form to submit during an automated test?

(I haven't figured out a way to simulate a keypress event that will cause a form submit.)

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/gwjnhujo/)  Have at it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What tool are you using to interact with the DOM? If you are using selenium, ENTER is an available keypress event that you can trigger on a particular element: http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Keys.html.

If you are testing with javascript, you can trigger a keypress directly:

```
var e = $.Event('keypress');
e.which = 13;
$('form').trigger(e);
```

EDIT --

In response to comment below, I see what you're getting at. I suspect that browsers specially handle that case of enter on a form field and fire a form submission event (after the keypress event has been evaluated)? So I don't think you can really emulate that behavior purely with javascript (though I may be wrong). I ran a quick test with selenium (which has as close to "native" browser events as you can get) and got the behavior you're looking for:

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> ff = webdriver.Firefox()
>>> ff.get('file:///home/justin/Desktop/test.html')
>>> from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
>>> el = ff.find_element_by_css_selector('#tbInput')
>>> el.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
# Alert popped up twice!
```

If you expect to be doing more UI testing along these lines, the investment in selenium might be worth it.

Comment: I've been using javascript (with QUnit).  I'll look into Selenium.  I copied and pasted your js code into my jsfiddle.  Triggering the event didn't work on neither `$('form')` nor `$(#tbinput)`.  If I added `e.keyCode = 13`, I could get the `keypress` event to fire on `#tbInput`, but the form's `submit` event still did not fire.